# Laptop makes connect/disconnect sound with nothing connected via bluetooth or USB

Tags: usb, audio, system-sounds

i first got this problem yesterday, i thought it was the mouse so i unplugged it, still happened, so i went online and thought i found a solution. I went into device manager and clicked on universal serial bus controllers and under USB root hub (xHCI) and unchecked the option where it would turn on or off a device. this appeared to work as i had no further problems until now. the problem happens roughly every 15 seconds and its always the connect and disconnect sound together. again, nothing is plugged in. Also when i open device manager and the sound happens i notice that under Universal serial bus controllers that two things disappear, generic superspeed USB hub, and USB composite device.
i have an HP Envy i bought about 2 years ago, i believe everything on it is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before. I had a USB extension (for 4 more) which kept turning itself off/on now and then. It was only £1 so I scrapped it and bought another.
If you're not listening to music and it doesn't affect what you're doing why not turn your sound off?